# Customize Springfox generation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm using springboot with springfox to generate swagger API.

I have 2 issues with springfox :
1) It doesn't support inheritance
2) It doesn't support JsonAnyGetter (as I would)

Could I override the json generation to customize the json and at runtime ?

For the first case, I'd like to add "allOf" for each subtypes.

For the second case I'd like to add a custom field.

My class is a generic class for pagination. Returning a paging info and a list under the "resourceName" field. Which is a parameter.
A PageWrapper of dogs will result in :

```
{
  "paging": { ...paging info ...},
  "dogs": [
   .. list of dogs ..
  ]
}
```

Class :

```
@ApiModel(value = "Page", description = "Page of results")
public class PageWrapper<T> {

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<T> objects;

    @JsonProperty("paging")
    private Paging paging;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String objectsName = "data";

    public PageWrapper(Page<T> page, String objectsName) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(objectsName)) {
            this.objectsName = objectsName;
        }
        this.objects = page.getContent();
        this.paging = new Paging(page.getTotalElements(), page.getNumber() * page.getSize() + 1, page.getSize());
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "content", value = "Page content")
    public Map<String, List<T>> data() {
        Map<String, List<T>> datas = new HashMap<>();
        datas.put(objectsName, objects);
        return datas;
    }
...
```

Comment: While its considered bad form to expose inheritance hierarchies over the wire, there are issues to address it. It will most likely be implemented in the next release. However its not clear what your expectation is on the `@JsonAnyxxxx` annotations. They imply open ended contracts, if the intent is to always have a pagination object (PaginationWrapper) why not make it explicit in the specification?

Comment: I don't really know how to not expose inheritance, it's another topic but I can be interested in it too :) How can you expose a PetList containing both dogs and cat for example ?

About the @JsonAnyGetter, I'm using it to change the field name of the objects returned in the json. I can have "new PageWrapper(list, "dogs");" and in another service "new PageWrapper(list, "cats")".
I have to name the list with the resource name.